# Problems with my Hangman game (Python)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I know this is long, please bear with me. I am taking this online class and our big project is to write code for the game Hangman. After looking online and finding some examples in order to help me get an idea of where to begin and how to go about this, I am almost done with the game. I am having just a few tiny issues that need to be cleaned up which I can't figure out how to fix. The first one deals with the spaces not lining up with the letters. So lets say the computer selects the word BASEBALL it will display `_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _` and it will seem to line up correctly. So if I guess B then it will show `B _ _ _ B _ _ _` and so on and so fourth, but as I add more and more letters, they don't line up. For instance, I will have `BA_EBALL _ _ _ _` when there is really only 1 letter left (the S). I don't know why or how it keeps adding extra blanks at the end. Another thing that I am having trouble with is repeat guesses. I programmed the game to display a message telling you to try again if you guess more than one letter or something that isn't a letter. I have a way to keep track of guessed letters, but for some reason it still allows for repeat guesses. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I apologize for this being so long and the code being longer.

```
import random
hangManPics = ['''<hangman art omitted>''']

words = 'AMERICAN NATIONAL BASEBALL BASE BALL STRIKE FOUL OUT\
 SINGLE DOUBLE TRIPLE HOMERUN PITCHER CATCHER OUTFIELD INFIELD\
 DIAMOND STADIUM CARDINALS DIAMONDBACKS BRAVES ORIOLES CUBS REDS\
 INDIANS ROCKIES TIGERS ASTROS ROYALS ANGELS DODGERS MARLINS\
 BREWER TWINS METS YANKEES ATHLETICS PHILLIES PIRATES PADRES\
 GIANTS MARINERS RAYS RANGERS NATIONALS STRIKEOUT RUNS FASTBALL\
 SLIDER CURVEBALL STEAL'

##  Select a random word from a word list
def getRandomWord(wordList):
    newWords = words.split()    ##  split the word list
    word = newWords[random.randint(0, len(newWords) - 1)]
    return word

def displayBoard(hangManPics, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord):
    print(hangManPics[len(missedLetters)])
    print()

    print("Missed letters:", end = '')
    for letter in missedLetters:
        print(letter, end = '')
    print()

    blanks = '_ ' * len(secretWord)

    for i in range(len(secretWord)):
        if secretWord[i] in correctLetters:
            blanks = blanks[:i] + secretWord[i] + blanks[i + 1:]

    for letter in blanks:
        print(letter, end = '')
    print()

def getGuess(alreadyGuessed):
    while True:
        guess = input("Please guess a letter. ")
        upperGuess = guess.upper()
        if len(upperGuess) != 1:
            print("Please enter a single letter.\n")
        elif guess in alreadyGuessed:
            print("You have already guessed that letter. Please select another one.\n")
        elif guess not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
            print("Your guess must be a letter.\n")
        else:
            return upperGuess

def playAgain():
    print("Would you like to play again? (yes or no)")
    return input().upper().startswith('Y')

print("H A N G M A N")
missedLetters = ''
correctLetters = ''
secretWord = getRandomWord(words)
endGame = False

while True:
    displayBoard(hangManPics, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord)

    guess = getGuess(missedLetters + correctLetters)

    if guess in secretWord:
        correctLetters = correctLetters + guess

        foundAllLetters = True
        for i in range(len(secretWord)):
            if secretWord[i] not in correctLetters:
                foundAllLetters = False
                break
        if foundAllLetters:
            print('''\<ascii art omitted>\n''')
            print("The secret word is", secretWord, ". You have won!\n")
            endGame = True
    else:
        missedLetters = missedLetters + guess

        if len(missedLetters) == len(hangManPics) - 1:
            displayBoard(hangManPics, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord)
            print('''<ascii art omitted>''')
            print("You have run out of guesses. The secret word is",\
                  secretWord, ". You lose.\n")
            endGame = True

    if endGame:
        if playAgain():
            missedLetters = ''
            correctLetters = ''
            endGame = False
            secretWord = getRandomWord(words)
        else:
            break

playAgain()
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (see also http://sscce.org) that replicates the issue. You could also consider reading ["how to debug small programs"](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Is this your entire code? If so, I get syntax errors when I try to run it. What version of Python are you using? Maybe there are new allowances in `print` statements I'm not aware of.

Comment: Split this question into 2 separate questions. Question 1: the `displayBoard` function. Get rid of all other functions, comment out the line about hangManPics and call with `displayBoard([], ['Z', 'K', 'C'], ['B', 'A', 'E', 'L'], 'BASEBALL')`. Question 2: `getGuess` function. Remove all other functions and call with `getGuess(['A', 'B', 'C'])  # Guessing "a" should produce error msg but does not`

Comment: I apologize jonrsharpe, I am new to this website so I am still learning about the format for posting. I will do that next time.

@dpwilson - yes this is my entire code (asside from the Hangman art, "Home Run", and "You're Out" art being edited out for formatting purposes on here) I am using Python 3.4 if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of your two problems are isolated to one function. In the future, you should debug each function individually:

1. Copy each function into a separate python file without the rest of the program (except for the very minimal you need to get the function to work)
2. Call the function with various example data until you are satisfied that the function is working or not
3. If the function is not working, get rid of anything inside the function that is not relevant to the problem. The less code you have, the easier it is to figure out what is wrong
4. If you cannot fix the problem yourself, ask a question about each *isolated* problem with the very minimal code you have created.

Here are answers for the two questions you would have had if you had isolated the problem:

**Problem 1: displayBoard function:**

The problem is that you forgot you have doubled the length of `blanks`, because you add a space for each letter: `blanks = '_ ' * len(secretWord)`. For each index `i` of `secretWord`, the index is `i*2` for `blanks`. Also, there is no need to print a word letter-by-letter. The fixed version is:

```
def displayBoard(hangManPics, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord):
    blanks = '_ ' * len(secretWord)

    for i in range(len(secretWord)):
        if secretWord[i] in correctLetters:
            blanks = blanks[:i*2] + secretWord[i] + blanks[i*2 + 1:]

    print(blanks)

displayBoard([], ['Z', 'K', 'C'], ['B', 'A', 'E', 'L'], 'BASEBALL')
```

An index-less way of doing it would be to replace all non-guessed letters with underscores, then insert the spaces between the letters:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

def displayBoard(hangManPics, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord):
    # print(hangManPics[len(missedLetters)])
    print()

    print("Missed letters: " + ''.join(missedLetters))

    # copy secretWord to blanked
    blanked = secretWord

    # Replace missing letters with blanks
    for letter in ascii_uppercase:
        if letter not in correctLetters:
            blanked = blanked.replace(letter, '_')

    # Add spaces between letters
    blanked = ' '.join(list(blanked))

    print(blanked)

displayBoard([], ['Z', 'K', 'C'], ['B', 'A', 'E', 'L'], 'BASEBALL')
```

**Problem 2: getGuess function:**

You make the input letter uppercase with `upperGuess = guess.upper()`, but then you continue to use the lowercase `guess`. Corrected version:

```
def getGuess(alreadyGuessed):
    while True:
        guess = input("Please guess a letter. ")
        upperGuess = guess.upper()
        if len(upperGuess) != 1:
            print("Please enter a single letter.\n")
        elif upperGuess in alreadyGuessed:
            print("You have already guessed that letter. Please select another one.\n")
        elif upperGuess not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.upper():
            print("Your guess must be a letter.\n")
        else:
            return upperGuess

getGuess(['A', 'B', 'C'])  # Guessing "a" should produce error
```